# setting screenOrientation in AndroidManifest.xml does not work

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, orientation, landscape-portrait

I have a simple hello world Android testing project. In my AndroidManifest.xml, I already set

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|keyboard|orientation">
```

but when I debug my code, the variable isLandscape is True when it should supposed to be False

```
boolean isLandscape = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
```

I know that I can also set the activity orientation by code, but I need to set it in xml for some reasons. How can I do it?

Edit: my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.androidgames.mreater"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" 
android:installLocation="preferExternal">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="Mr. Eater" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.androidgames.mreater.MrEaterGame"
        android:label="Mr. Eater" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

my actual onCreate activity method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    boolean isLandscape = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    int frameBufferWidth = isLandscape ? 480 : 320;
    int frameBufferHeight = isLandscape ? 320 : 480;
   Bitmap frameBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameBufferWidth,
            frameBufferHeight, Config.RGB_565);

    float scaleX = (float) frameBufferWidth
            / getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    float scaleY = (float) frameBufferHeight
            / getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    renderView = new AndroidFastRenderView(this, frameBuffer);
    graphics = new AndroidGraphics(getAssets(), frameBuffer);
    fileIO = new AndroidFileIO(getAssets());
    audio = new AndroidAudio(this);
    input = new AndroidInput(this, renderView, scaleX, scaleY);
    screen = this.getStartScreen();
   setContentView(renderView);

    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "GLGame");
}
```

Now it's getting more weird, the isLandscape variable is True, but sometimes it is False. It's somehow like a bug.

Comment: Does the screen orientation actually change or just that the variable is returning true?

Comment: You are setting it on the activity tag right? Not putting it in the application tag? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen

Comment: the Activity screen is in landscape, not in portrait as I want.

Comment: @KenWolf yes. I set it in activity tag.

Comment: @CuồnYết weird. I literally just tried this and can't replicate the problem. This problem on all devices/emulators?

Comment: Try removing `orientation` from `android:configChanges`.

Comment: @W.K.S thanks, but it does not work.

Comment: @KenWolf I both try it in BlueStacks emulator and device, and now it's getting more weird that sometimes the variable is True, sometimes is False. it's somehow like a bug.

Answer (score 12):

Make sure you put it in the `<activity>` tag, not the `<application>` tag.

It only works in the `<activity>` tag, but will not complain if you put it in the `<application>` tag.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

vs

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

You will need to put it for each `Activity` you define in your `manifest.xml`

Comment: thanks Ken Wolf but I put it in activity tag, not application tag.

Comment: I don't know what it is then, everything seems fine from what you've described. Maybe edit your post and add your `manifest.xml`? We need more clues :)

Comment: @CuồnYết, you must declare `screeSize` too if your declared target API is 13 or higher.

Comment: One more thing I thought of (long shot) - make sure there's not some other error preventing you from building and that you are actually testing the latest version of your app. Make a small change to a string or something and see if that gets through.

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems okay, except one thing! I don't know if it's your case or not, but you should read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) :D

You will have to declare `screeSize` if you applications targets API level 13 or higher.

> If your application targets API level 13 or higher (as declared by the
>   minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), then you should also
>   declare the "screenSize" configuration, because it also changes when a
>   device switches between portrait and landscape orientations.

Let me know it this resolves your issue.

Comment: thanks yugidroid. my applications targets API level is 17. I have added the  "screenSize" configuration, but it does not work. the activity is still in landscape.