# Issue when trying to fix orientation screen to natural or default orientation

Tags: android, orientation, android-manifest

I would like to lock the screen orientation specifying the configuration in the AndroidManifest, instead of doing it programmatically. So I've ended up with the following approach:

*values/config.xml*

```
<resources>
    <integer name="orientation">1</integer>
</resources>
```

*values-sw600dp/config.xml*

```
<resources>
    <integer name="orientation">0</integer>
</resources>
```

If I check the value’s resource programmatically

```
getResources().getInteger(R.integer.orientation)
```

I get the expected value: 0 for tablets and 1 for handsets, which is the value specified by the framework for landscape and portrait orientation respectively.

But if I use this resource in the AndroidManifest:

```
<activity
            android:name="activities.InitialConfigActivity_"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="@integer/orientation" />
```

The activity always launches in portrait mode, regardless if it is a tablet or a handset device.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**  I originally read your question to mean you wanted complete control over the start-up orientation.  If you are satisfied to get the natural/default orientation, then use `nosensor` as described below.

---

This may not qualify as an answer--I had more to share than could be put in a comment.

You've probably already looked at the discussion in these related issues: [related-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104958/change-manifest-screenorientation-with-values?rq=1), [related-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327025/setting-screenorientation-in-androidmanifest-xml-does-not-work?rq=1), [related-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642792/setting-android-activity-screen-orientation-with-values-xml).

In my experience, when an issue has been investigated by a number of different people for a period of four years, with no solution found, it usually means there is no solution.

One option might be to use the [nosensor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#screenOrientation) orientation in your manifest:

android:screenOrientation="nosensor"

This starts the activity in the device's "default" or "natural" orientation.  On my devices this is: phone=portrait, 7-inch-tablet=portrait, 10-inch-tablet=landscape. Won't work for you if you want landscape for 7-inch tablet.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553650/how-to-check-device-natural-default-orientation-on-android-i-e-get-landscape) includes code for determining what a device's default orientation is.